# Help finding Integration Factor to convert Exact ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I just need someone to point out my mistake, I'm trying to find the integrating factor to make the following equation an exact ODE.

$$\frac{x+y}{y-1}dx-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x+y}{y-1})^2dy=0$$

I multiplied the original equation by -2 for my own ease to make it

$$\frac{-2x-2y}{y-1}dx+(\frac{x+y}{y-1})^2dy=0$$

so it matches the form

\begin{equation*}
M(x,y)dx+N(x,y)dy=0
\end{equation*}

So far I've worked out that

\begin{equation*}
\frac {\partial M} {\partial y}=\frac{2x+2}{(y-1)^2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\frac {\partial N} {\partial x}=\frac{2(x+y)}{(y-1)^2}
\end{equation*}

leading me to my frustration

Test Case 1
\begin{equation*}
\frac {1} {N}*(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x})=\frac{2-2y}{(x+y)^2}
\end{equation*}

Test Case 2
\begin{equation*}
\frac {1} {M}*(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial Y})=\frac{-1}{y+x}
\end{equation*}

both are failing for me and I am at wits end on where am I wrong any form of guidance will be much MUCH appreciated

Comment: If you cancel one factor $(x+y)$, the resulting DE is linear in $x$, so you should find an integrating factor as function of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{x+y}{y-1}dx-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x+y}{y-1})^2dy=0$$
$$2({y-1})dx-({x+y})dy=0$$
I substituted $u=y-1$ and $v=x+1$ for simplicity:
$$2udv-({u+v})du=0$$
$$(2udv-vdu)-udu=0$$
Divide by $2\sqrt u$:
$$(\sqrt udv-\dfrac 1{2\sqrt u}vdu)-\dfrac {\sqrt u} 2du=0$$
$$d(\dfrac v {\sqrt u})-\dfrac 1{2\sqrt u}du=0$$
Integration gives:
$$v(u)=u+c\sqrt u$$
Finally:
$$x(y)=y-2+c\sqrt {y-1}$$

Comment: oops, I just realized you also multiplied divided both terms by $x+y$.

Comment: @nickalh Yes I dod that in th frst step no problem